# Cannot read property 'createPromiseCapability' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, amd, systemjs, pdf.js

I'm trying to use `ngx-extended-pdf-viewer` in an Angular project that uses `amd.min.js` as an dependency. If I remove amd as an dependency it's working fine. But sadly I can't remove it as, a lot of other things are dependent on it.

Here's the reproducible html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Hi Duniya</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/4.0.0/system.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/4.0.0/extras/amd.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/4.0.0/extras/named-exports.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/4.0.0/extras/named-register.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer@9.0.0-alpha.5/assets/pdf.worker-2.7.684.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer@9.0.0-alpha.5/assets/pdf-2.7.684.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer@9.0.0-alpha.5/assets/viewer-2.7.684.js"></script>    
</head>
<body>
    hello
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load all three pdf modules before amd.

```
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer@9.0.0-alpha.5/assets/pdf.worker-2.7.684.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer@9.0.0-alpha.5/assets/pdf-2.7.684.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer@9.0.0-alpha.5/assets/viewer-2.7.684.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/4.0.0/system.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/4.0.0/extras/amd.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/4.0.0/extras/named-exports.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/4.0.0/extras/named-register.min.js"></script>
```

**Explanation**

`pdf-viewer.js` checks for the presence of `pdf` module in window object. But, when `amd` module is loaded first `pdf.js` don't store in window object but register it as an amd module.

```
else if(typeof define === 'function' && define.amd)
    define("pdfjs-dist/build/pdf", [], factory);
```

If you load `pdf.js` before `amd`, following line gets executed which makes `pdf` module available in window object(root is window).

```
root["pdfjs-dist/build/pdf"] = root.pdfjsLib = factory();
```

Snippets mentioned above are from https://unpkg.com/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer@9.0.0-alpha.5/assets/pdf-2.7.684.js